# Правописание мужских фамилий в родительном падеже

Tags: орфография

Как пишутся в родительном падеже мужские фамилии: Асатрян, Воротеляк, Рева?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно: Асатряна, Воротеляка, РевЫ.

Замечание. Мне показалась, что у вас фамилия Рев, поэтому я написал РеВА.

По правилам, все фамилии, кончающиеся на неударное ***а*** после согласных, склоняются по первому склонению.

См.:[Грамота.ру, **п.13.1.11.**](http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Bsearch%2F%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=808.5eBjLnBGgK0k942WO8vBZ0QKJW8h-0fsuS48lp4IpVJ9xDJE2knK9HZIFV1w7ze1Mhr823UpD5HKwv1bM6I4Rwwlx7Bm02-1pAMjz1PuzOpQon4E2svTL5rKrN75WBPg.540807934b968cf8d0be74d57762a673c86f68d9&url=http%3A%2F%2Fnew.gramota.ru%2Fspravka%2Fletters%2F22-spravka%2Fletters%2F71-rubric-482&uuid=&state=PEtFfuTeVD5kpHnK9lio9XPOnieP7YQBovzVqj9ang0YEepmskggOQ%3D%3D&data=&b64e=3&sign=1b9ee9399b8ae0c6c30d48be436a6710&keyno=0&cst=AiuY0DBWFJ5Hyx_fyvalFFO69YeYKfJ6N6-eex9rvtPotv75wbS4xdLPVbkCRsMms3YsFVE-Dub6a62rR_0vfLuAsBv6mplCGIbH50VeA7emrPVfyB5UC3Wo8BCiWIfjmT8GW_SFYqbKH4bzFtlJAOWxaiI7PVOulZQN7-NDcx593q_Tc9-zGMzAnTL71e9HSs8_57Pxqd26kmPp3LCsdB_k6xsD0__s&ref=cM777e4sMOAycdZhdUbYHpMQ80108_UCHDaAO0SZ3A5-O7V9SFxpVpEthr5IGc9wn4dOBWq0v96hLk-fxLE_LA9oJZHd-t27eGNnaZn9sDOHuER1t-emjCItm-UhO1zYya0HQ1DpXxj56LGe600LFuP8U6Hp_sSTFqMWBYcs3Lsdk61mzKdOaXP0j86STBEZlgIIVVaVriOmjDA9qjhSzuYlwZP4RFaPs9MKbxcx0ynItVWO9lp0Z7iWYV48FCsR41YK7F1R-p2KXY0vOwENhT450j_acG2EPOvzOVJ4sHtjuVHCui6qLlQZSaYgIOrnkjdy1-vQd562NmE9dL1MQeRrndGJRFKg_98arP88q57XvBy76vIUe2Kp0yWQiFgDaosASttGy-XVtQP9mNgOZ_M79K1U6uXlc95o6A0xhTXI4v5GIXSIIFlkL8iAntcFkl8EAzQyHl6VRlTtZaKhW3_JX2TIsolobVg28WzMl2E85JKoJGmYneuCktV3sc1tNxn0MHGpvvGxq015mio0KFINYIbfef8AhviDC8BlEaFbQpUgtNRkt9H6ltzvDPj0IzPMcOjNojIG-e8ghq9-sbLE-IyFlgmgg9396MYffd4wRLII0phuVg&l10n=ru&cts=1441956365483&mc=5.155427571922582)

Answer (score 0):

«Я знаю Александра Реву». Вспомните всем известную передачу Comedy Club!

Comment: Тагрикс, фамилия РевУ - стоит в винительном падеже, а не в родительном. И образована она от фамилии Рева.

Comment: У человека из телевизора фамилия Ревва (два "в").

Comment: Один черт, сколько там "В". На склонение никак не влияет. А в остальном Серж прав (по состоянию на данный момент).